# How to stretch or scale a windows to fit resolution height and width sizes?

Tags: windows-7

I need some software to stretch or scale a windows to fit resolution sizes.

E.g., I have a program that does not allow to be maximized or to change its windows size, that is 640x480. With that software I ask you, **I would scale** that windows and all visual elements inside it to fit resolution height **or** I would **stretch** any **windows and all visual elements inside them** to **fit all resolution (1360x768)**.

So I'm searching for some kind of "sandbox" or "magnify glass" but that do not affect features of the program I want to resize, like network access, use of keyboard and mouse... i.e. I would like to see live video output from the stretched/scaled window (not a screenshot) and work in it (I could press buttons, type some text in edit boxes etc.)

Edit1: I don't want changing resolution, but only changing "scale" of a particular opened window...

Edit2: I "heard" that in Mac OS X and some Linux distros like Ubuntu 8+ you can zoom in some screen area pressing OS Symbol (Apple Key or Linux Key) and scrolling the mouse wheel. In Windows 7 I also heard about doing that with WinKey and +/- keys, but differently from Mac OS X and Ubuntu, you can only read the contents of magnified area, i.e., you cannot click in buttons, edit text or see animated images... if someone could show me a magnified work-allowed screen like Mac OS X and Ubuntu for Windows, I would assign the answer for him/her.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> keys should work fine for you if you do not care about the rest of the applications while you are scaling this one up. The Windows 7 Magnifier tool can be set to full screen zoom, with almost any zoom factor, and it does not disable any interactions or animations. You can also set it to not follow the mouse pointer or keyboard focus, so the view is fixed once you have everything set up.

If you see a docked window, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to switch to full screen view. Note that this is only valid for Windows 7 *with Aero enabled*. Windows XP's magnifier is always a docked window with no interaction.

Comment: Okay, so the Windows magnifier does not scale individual windows... But from the question it seems like you want only one window to scale to fit the entire monitor. As I said, Windows Magnifier will do that.

Comment: @kokbira - Using the desktop magnification as Soumya92 has suggested (WinKey + "numpad +/-") does allow video, button pressing, text box usage etcetera while zoomed.

Comment: @Kokbira See updated answer

Comment: Nice! It is what I was searching for! You are the guy, @Soumya92. You can improve the answer informing that Full Screen is allowed only when Aero is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use [**Sizer**](http://www.brianapps.net/sizer/), which works well for this.  Unfortunately, there is no version for 64-bit Windows, so I do not use it any more, and I am unaware of anything similar.

[image: Sizer]

Answer (score 1):

Try [ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/).

> ResizeEnable lets you turn usually non-resizeable windows into resizeable windows.
>   Most windows will respond correctly, but some may not!

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Comment: it only enables expanding the window box (windows and height only), but it does not resize the window contents (e.g. a button with 12px in height remains with the same height).

Comment: @kokbira Was worth a shot. Good luck in your search.

Comment: I already tested it. Before asking here, I downloaded, installed and tested a lot of tools... I called your help´because none of them functioned as I would like. Later I'll post a picture of what I would like to see...

Answer (score 0):

The product [ZoomText Express](http://www.bigshotmagnifier.com/zoomtextexpress) might be useful, using the Full Window zooming option. It costs $49.99, trial version available.

Its "big brother" product [ZoomText](http://www.bigshotmagnifier.com/zoomtext) is much costlier, and trial is also available.

I don't know, however, whether it answers your particular needs.