# How do I enlarge a game but not make it full screen?

Tags: windows-7, parallels, imac, magnifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stretch or scale a windows to fit resolution height and width sizes?](https://superuser.com/questions/311298/how-to-stretch-or-scale-a-windows-to-fit-resolution-height-and-width-sizes)

I'm playing a game in windowed mode, unfortunately my screen is huge 2560x1440 or something and the game window is tiny. If I use fullscreen it blows up and looks atrocious. I just want to enlarge the window by 2x or 3x.

I'm using the windows magnifier option but moving my mouse around makes the screen zoom around unusably. Is there a way to just magnify one program/window and fix it?

Comment: @TomWijsman - IMO, Same question: "I need some software to stretch or scale a windows to fit resolution sizes." vs. "Is there a way to just magnify one program/window and fix it?", even if the accepted answer doesn't quite match this case 100%, there are others to check and consider.  But hey, that's why it takes 5 to close. :)

Comment: It might help if you're more specific about the game - certain rendering engines will choke and die even if you have some other way of doing this.  I know Diablo II is impossible to enlarge without modifying it, for example - you can't scale it internally any other way and I'm under the impression zooming it causes the 2D drawing mechanisms to act weird.

Comment: @Shinrai \: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELF_Corporation#YU-NO

Comment: @Mark - Well that explains the lack of resolution-shifting support.  Something that simple you can probably get by with a zoom app (I unfortunately don't know of a universal one for Windows that behaves as desired, but I see you have a neat workaround at least)

Comment: So, now it is a duplicate...

Answer (score 1):

**Mark mentioned:**

I set 'magnify follow' to follow text insertion.

Since my game doesn't have any text insertion the screen doesn't move around. Yay.

Comment: The game is from 1996, it has a resolution of really tiny. I want to make it bigger.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not a good solution for me at the moment, I need the rest of my computer.

Comment: Well I call it a game, but it's more like a book... It's a visual novel. Thanks for your help though.