# Setting laptop built-in display's resolution below 1024x768?

Tags: windows-8, display, resolution

I can't find a way to set my laptop's display below 1024x768 resolution. The Windows 8.1 'low resolution' mode (640x480) works, but that cannot really be used with multiple monitors etc. The laptop has integrated Intel and NVIDIA GPUs.

EDIT: Can't create custom resolution using Intel's drivers, because I need to use 800x600 as desktop resolution, not only on a specific application.

Comment: It might help if you explain the context.  Why are you trying to set that low of a resolution?

Comment: We're trying to find a way to run a browser java-based game, which is locked at 800x600, and the browser zoom cannot actually zoom it in. Even though we could use, for example, the Windows low resolution launch option, that only supports one display.

Comment: Related: [Force Windows 8 Metro apps to run lower resolutions below 1024x768?](http://superuser.com/questions/396846/force-windows-8-metro-apps-to-run-lower-resolutions-below-1024x768?rq=1)

Comment: Have you tried messing with DPI scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set it lower because the minimum required resolution for Windows 8.1 is 1024x768.

> The minimum native resolution/color depth is 1024x768 at a depth of 32bits.

Source: [Windows Hardware Certification Requirements for Client and Server Systems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj128256)

Also see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_8#Hardware_requirements

Comment: Seriously? No way to at least 'zoom in' ? 21st century guys -.- If it can run safe mode at even lower resolutions, surely there's some way to emulate it somehow to have 800x600

Comment: Did you try the [Windows Magnifier](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/use-magnifier-see-items)?

Comment: Very few settings on it + it cannot zoom in just one display or show zoomed in java application

Comment: Perhaps check out: [How to stretch or scale a windows to fit resolution height and width sizes?](http://superuser.com/questions/311298/how-to-stretch-or-scale-a-windows-to-fit-resolution-height-and-width-sizes)

Comment: Nothing worked, even the registry tweak.. oh well

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try Going Here :

- Right Click on Desktop (*On Empty Place and Wallpapers*)
- Click on Screen Resolution
- Click on Advanced Settings
- Click List All Modes
  and Check if it works

Sorry in Advanced for Grammar Mistake and Wrong Guidence